# Why is it recommended to not use a device while charging? How does it harm the battery or the device?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

I was planning on getting the new VR headset from Oculus, dubbed *Oculus GO*.

The battery life of that thing is roughly 3 hours max. So, during long VR sessions, powering the headset via a power bank seems to be a great solution, but many people were against this method.

According to them, it is not recommended and it simply degrades the battery's life. So I have some few questions:

**Q:** Why is charging and using the device at the same time considered to be bad for the device?

**Q:** How is a battery affected by this method?

**Q:** Why haven't we developed a battery that can remain unaffected while using it during charging?

**Q:** What is the factor that gives a battery this demerit?

Comment: *but many people were against this method* Next time, ask these people: **why**? As Spehro's answer explains, in a properly designed device there are no reasons why you cannot charge and use a device at the same time. There are many people with "opinions" about technical stuff, there are few that can actually back their opinion up with **hard facts**. In my opinion, if you cannot backup such opinions with facts then those opinions are worthless and can be ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's nothing whatsoever to do with the battery.

The product manufacturer chose to design the charger/power supply circuit that way. Most cell phones, for example, can be used perfectly well while they are being charged from a cable or wirelessly.

The power supply is called upon to supply more current if it is called upon to charge the battery and run the device at the same time, so it might cost a bit more, be a bit more complex or be a bit larger. They made their choice, your options are to buy it or not, unless you have the skills to re-engineer it.

Comment: On top of that, I would like to add timeout which may affect the application and the manufacturer don't want questions about it. No harm though, but perhaps an error indication from the device or as simple as manual says it will take two hours to recharge and customer service gets questions when it takes three.

Answer (score 4):

If your taking charge and using your device at the same time, then one thing to consider is there will be more heat. Overheating is known to be a factor which can degrade the health of your battery and its ability to hold charge.